# Calcular valores desde una tabla a otra

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

me gustaría saber como puedo calcular los valores "usado" y "cantidad" de dos modelos que generé con anterioridad llamados **bidon** y **control**.

Este es el schema

```
create_table "bidons", force: :cascade do |t|
t.integer  "usado"
t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
end

  create_table "control", force: :cascade do |t|
t.integer "bidon_id"
t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
t.integer  "cantidad"
end
```

En el modelo bidon tengo lo siguiente:

```
class Bidon < ActiveRecord::Base #bank
    has_many :controls, dependent: :destroy

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :controls


    validates :name, presence: true

    def to_s
        name
    end
end
```

Acá utilizo **accepts_nested_attributes_for** para editar la cantidad actual de bidones desde el modelo bidon. (Con esto no tengo problemas).

En el modelo control tengo:

```
class Control < ActiveRecord::Base #bank_subsidiaries
  belongs_to :bidon
  validates :cantidad, presence: true

  def to_s
    cantidad
  end
end
```

Lo que me gustaría hacer es calcular los valores : usado y cantidad en el caso de crear o editar un bidon, la idea es que la cantidad de control se modifique.

***Tengo que hacerlo desde el controlador Bidon en este caso?***

***En el controlador de los bidones que debo establecer para que estos valores se calculen?***

```
 def create
    #@bidon = Bidon.new(bidon_params)
    @bidon = Bidon.new(bidon_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @bidon.save
        format.html { redirect_to @bidon, notice: 'Bidon was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @bidon }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @bidon.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /bidons/1
  # PATCH/PUT /bidons/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @bidon.update(bidon_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @bidon, notice: 'Bidon was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @bidon }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @bidon.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_bidon
      @bidon = Bidon.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def bidon_params
      params.require(:bidon).permit(:name, :usado, controls_attributes: [:id, :cantidad])
    end
end
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi formulario me muestra *la cantidad disponible en el control*, entonces ahora al ingresar la cantidad usada, supongamos que quiero sumarlo, debería quedar un total reflejado en la cantidad total del control nada más.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muchas gracias!

Comment: Es decir, lo que quieres es que lo que "use" producción, se acumule en  la `cantidad` del bidon? Y guardar las "producciones" en tu base de datos. Es así?

Comment: Asumo que `Producción` pertenece a `Bidon` y que `Bidón` tiene muchas `producciones`, es eso correcto?

Comment: Si, que solo exista una cantidad final, pero que sea la cantidad utilizada de la tabla bidons, es un stock principal. Producción pertene a bidon y bidon tiene muchas producciones.

Answer (score 0):

**app/models/produccion.rb**

```
class Produccion < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :bidon
end
```

**app/models/bidon.rb**

```
class Bidon < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :produccions
end
```

**app/controllers/produccions_controller.rb**

```
class ProduccionsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    # Encuentra el bidon a través de los params.
    bidon = Bidon.find(params[:bidon_id]

    # una vez encontrado el bidon, haz una producción nueva que pertenezca 
    # a ese bidon y con los params que fueron enviados a través de la forma.
    @produccion = bidon.produccions.new(produccions_params)

    if @produccion.save
      # actualiza la cantidad en bidon, esto es lo que ya tenga de cantidad
      # más lo que se haya usado en esta producción
      bidon.cantidad += @produccion.usado

      # guarda el bidon
      bidon.save
    else
      render :new
    end
  end
end
```

Básicamente lo que esta propuesta hace es que cuando se cree una prducción, esta incluya en sus params (esto se agrega en la forma) el id del bidón seleccionado y así crear la producción a partir del bidon (ya que pertence al bidon).

Comment: Otro camino podría ser que como usuario, primero selecciones el `bidon` y ya con el bidon "activo" crees un `producto`. Esta opción haría innecesario el agregar `bidon_id` a los params, puesto que ya sabrías con cual bidon estás trabajando.

Comment: Lo intente con esa logica, pero me salta: Couldn't find Bidon with 'id'=

Comment: Es porque `bidon_id` no está en los params. Tienes que agregarlo manualmente. Como hacerlo, depende de cómo estés implementando la forma. Por ejemplo, una opción es que en la línea en donde creas la forma (form_for @produccion...) le agregues el parámetro `url: produccions_path(bidon_id: la-manera-que-tengas-de-identificar-el-bidon)`.

Comment: Una vez que puedas pasar el `bidon_id` a tus params, vas a necesitar agregar nested attributes a tu método `produccions_params`. Esto es para que puedas modificar el objeto `bidon` desde el controllador `produccions`

Comment: cambie la publicación con algo mas especifico, me podrías dar una mano al respecto por favor?

Comment: con base a la actualización, tengo la siguiente duda: `control.cantidad` no es directamente editable por el usuario desde la forma, es decir veo la cantidad disponible pero no la puedo cambiar. Esa sólo es para mostrar cuanto hay disponible, pero el campo que si puedo modificar es `bidon.usado`. Es así?

Comment: Sí, es editable desde el formulario en bidons/1/edit, y en controls/4/edit y también cuando se crea el control, esto siempre y cuando un control tenga asignado un bidón, pero si no tengo ningún bidón no me muestra la cantidad disponible del stock principal . Lo que quiero lograr es calcular estas cantidades o encontrar la forma de solo tener un stock principal y desde ahi hacer operaciones con dicha cantidad. Adjunto foto nueva.

Comment: Gracias por la aclaración Mosiah. Ahora, solo para confirmar, puedes tener más de un Bidon, verdad? Lo pregunto por tu comentario de "solo tener un stock principal".

Comment: Claro, es una bodega, un bidón pueden ser digamos una cantidad de 1000 de Stock, y ese bidón ese ID 1 - yo lo que quiero lograr es encontrar la lógica para utilizar un Stock principal y cuando lo use desde otros modelos se vaya descontando.